# Referencing array index in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I was under impression that references in Ruby are equivalent to pointers in C.  But I'm confused by this:

```
ar = [1, 2, 3, 4]
first = ar[0] # => 1
ar.shift # => 1
ar # => [2, 3, 4]
first # => 1
```

Shouldn't `first` point to the memory address of `ar[0]`,  which holds the value `2`? Why does it still hold to the expired value?

What is the Ruby way to let `first` equal to the current value of `ar[0]`?

Answer (score 1):

You assigned the variable `first` to whatever the first element was at the time. Since `ar[0]` was 1 at the time, it was exactly the same as just saying `first = 1`.

It’s not the same as calling `ar.first`, which always points to the first element (synonymous with `ar[0]`).

Ruby uses what it calls an `object_id` to keep track of each object instance. When you say `first = ar[0]`, Ruby assigns `first` to the same object that's in `ar[0]`. These two objects will remain in sync, and any mutations that you perform to them will stay in sync, since it's exactly the same object in memory. If you re-assign either variable (`ar[0]` or `first`) to a different object, you'll lose your sync.

```
irb(main):001:0> ar = ['a','b','c']
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
irb(main):002:0> first = ar[0]
=> "a"
irb(main):003:0> ar[0] << ' testing!'
=> "a testing!"
irb(main):004:0> first
=> "a testing!"
irb(main):005:0> ar[0].replace('this is a test')
=> "this is a test"
irb(main):006:0> ar
=> ["this is a test", "b", "c"]
irb(main):007:0> first
=> "this is a test"
irb(main):008:0> ar[0].object_id
=> 70159033810680
irb(main):009:0> first.object_id
=> 70159033810680
irb(main):010:0> ar[0] = 'different string instance'
=> "different string instance"
irb(main):011:0> ar
=> ["different string instance", "b", "c"]
irb(main):012:0> first
=> "this is a test"
irb(main):013:0> ar[0].object_id
=> 70159033712320
```

The `<<` method and `replace` methods mutate the string object. If you're using Rails and familiar with ActiveRecord, it'd be like doing:

```
user1 = User.new(first_name: 'Bob')
user2 = User.new(first_name: 'Joe')
user3 = User.new(first_name: 'Dave')

ar = [user1, user2, user3]
first = ar[0]
```

In the end, all you did was `first = user1`

If you do `user1.first_name = 'Jim'`, you'll now see that `ar[0]`, `user1`, and `first` all had the `first_name` changed, because you mutated the ActiveRecord object.

Numbers are immutable. You cannot change the object that's in memory. You cannot change a `1` to be a `5`. All you can do is update your variable to use a different object instance.

```
irb(main):014:0> testing = 1 + 5
=> 6
irb(main):015:0> testing.object_id
=> 13
irb(main):016:0> 6.object_id
=> 13
```

`6` is basically a constant. You can't change 1, you can't change 5, but you can add them together to get 6.

Quick side note about `object_id`. Some of the Ruby core object ids are pretty constant, but just pretend they aren't predictable. They're meant for you to be able to compare two objects easily. Some functions in Ruby user the object_id to determine equality, because if the object_id of two different variables are the same, then they are definitely equal, since they point to the same memory location.

Any time you create write string literal, you create a new object in memory.

```
irb(main):017:0> a = 'testing'
=> "testing"
irb(main):018:0> b = 'testing'
=> "testing"
irb(main):019:0> a.object_id
=> 70159025508120
irb(main):020:0> b.object_id
=> 70159029161840
```

If you mutate `a`, then `b` does not change because they are different objects. If you're passing a string variable around, it's important to know whether the action you're calling is mutative or not, and whether or not you actually want mutation.

For example, you may at some point in life create an array.

```
ar = ['a','b','c']
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

And then decide you want to use pass that first element of the array into a function argument, or store it in a variable.

```
first = ar[0]
=> "a"
```

This is fine as long as you don't mutate. Well, maybe you're wanting to change your `first` variable for some reason. Perhaps you're building a list of HTML classes.

```
first << ' some cool text'
=> "a some cool text"

first
=> "a some cool text"
```

All seems fine, right?

But, look what that did to your array.

```
ar
=> ["a some cool text", "b", "c"]
```

If you see a time when you want to mutate a variable that was passed in, one thing you can do is assign your variable to a copy of it.

```
first = ar[0].dup
```

Now, `first` is the same string value as `ar[0]`, but a new string instance. You can safely mutate `first` or `ar[0]` without changing the other one.

Mutation isn't always bad. It can be very helpful. But, unexpected mutations can be really confusing if you don't know they're happening. Especially if you're mutating an argument to a function, because the original value was defined elsewhere and now it's changed.

Ruby tends to end method names with `!` if there's a mutable version of it. Like `sub` vs `sub!` in a string. `sub` returns a new string with your substitutions applied, leaving the original string alone. `sub!` modifies (aka mutates) the string you call it on.

Comment: I would say it is exactly the same as with pointers in e.g. C. If you assign a variable in C to the value at a particular address, this variable will also not change if the value at that particular address changes. See https://ideone.com/ACpxcv for a rough C translation of the OP's code that gives the exact same result.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Good point. I've updated my answer to not mention Pointers, since I don't have enough C knowledge to actually be helpful comparing the two, and added more Ruby examples.

Comment: @Nate  Thank you for you explanation!

Comment: @Jorg   Sorry I wasn't clear enough,  I realize in C you declare pointer with a  *, like "int *first".

Comment: @SethModu, @JörgWMittag’s comment was in response to a previous version of my answer, which I’ve since changed to reduce confusion, since I don’t know enough C and was trying to make comparisons to C incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the Ruby way to let first equal to the current value of ar[0]?

If you really wanted to you could make `first` a method rather than a local variable such as

```
ar = [1, 2, 3, 4]
define_method(:first, &ar.method(:first))
first #=> 1
ar.shift # => 1
ar # => [2, 3, 4]
first # => 2
```

**Note:** While this answers your question I am not endorsing this as a viable concept since a subsequent definition of first e.g. (`first = 12`) will result in `first #=> 12` (local variable) and `first() #=> 2` (method call)